rest_cannot_update error
I got this error when i try to post article on my blog via python using rest api. everything works but got error when i try to add seo rankmath meta description.
Response: {"code":"rest_cannot_update","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to edit the rank_math_description custom field.","data":{"key":"rank_math_description","status":403}}
I register meta keys using the below code
function register_custom_meta_keys() {
register_meta('post', 'rank_math_focus_keyword', array(
    'type' => 'string',
    'description' => 'Focus keyword for Rank Math SEO',
    'single' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
));

register_meta('post', 'rank_math_title', array(
    'type' => 'string',
    'description' => 'SEO Title for Rank Math',
    'single' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
));

register_meta('post', 'rank_math_description', array(
    'type' => 'string',
    'description' => 'SEO Description for Rank Math',
    'single' => true,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
));

}
add_action('init', 'register_custom_meta_keys');

As a third party plugin, Rankmath is off topic for this Stack. Your best venue for support would be the plugin's own support forum.

The status code 403 (Forbidden) in the response suggests that your request is not properly authenticated.
You could start by reviewing the REST API handbook section on Authentication, in case there's something you may have missed, and double-checking the credentials, if any, you're using with to make the request.
You can also pass auth_callback as one of the $args to register_meta(), if you need to customize the meta update capability checking.

auth_callback - A function or method to call when performing
edit_post_meta, add_post_meta, and delete_post_meta capability checks.

Or contact the plugin author's customer support as Chris Cox mentioned in the comments.
